# EMongoCriteria : Limit and Group By show less rows

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I am using MongoDB, with PHP YII. I have used YiiMongoDbSuite for setting up the criteria for mongoDB Queries.

Currently, I am using Group by and Limit together. But due to some reason queries are returning less number of rows than that are expected.

```
$criteria=new EMongoCriteria();

$criteria->group('col_1'); 
$criteria->limit(10); 
$result = TableName::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Can somebody guide me as I am quite new to MongoDB and YiiMongoDbSuite.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please write what are you expecting to get and what are you actually getting.

Comment: What Yii Extension are you using? It is likely that the `group` function is the old Map Reduce one which is technically deprecated in favour of using the aggregation framework instead. Plus grouping does not work like this in MongoDB

Comment: @Sammaye I am using EMongoCriteria

Comment: That is the class within the ext, what is the ext called? EMongoDbSuite, MongoYii, etc?

Comment: @ChristianP I want to limit query result to 10, with group query. any solution will be considered.

Comment: @Sammaye my Bad, copied wrong text. it is "YiiMongoDbSuite"

Answer (score 1):

Well to do it using [MongoYii](https://github.com/Sammaye/MongoYii) (which I maintain):

```
$result = MongoModel::model()->aggregate(
    array(
        '$group' => array('_id' => 'col_1'), 
        '$limit' => 10
    )
)
```

I am unsure how to do it with YiiMongoDbSuite, in fact there is no `group` command in its `EMongoCriteria` from what I see.